# Based on their respective number of degrees of freedom, what's the most efficient fuel; hydrogen or gasoline?

Tags: thermodynamics, combustion, hydrocarbons, fuel

The reaction of octane's combustion is:

$$\ce{2 C8H18 + 25 O2 -> 18 H2O + 16 CO2}$$

I am asked for computing the number of degrees of freedom of the octane given that its specific heat is $\pu{256 JK^{-1}mol^{-1}}$.

Then I have to compare the number of degrees of freedom obtained for octane with those for $\ce{H2}$. Based on this I have to argue what's the most efficient fuel.

**What I've done**

I assumed octane stores thermal energy only in quadratic degrees of freedom and these do not depend on $T$. Using the equipartition theorem one gets:

$$C_V = \frac{\partial U}{\partial T} = \frac{Nfk_\mathrm B}{2} = \frac{nfR}{2} $$

Where: $k_\mathrm B = \pu{1.381 \times 10^{-23}JK^{-1}}$ and $R = \pu{8.315 JK^{-1}mol^{-1}}$

Then for octane:

$$C_V = fR $$

$$f = 31$$

***Aren't these too many degrees of freedom?***

For $\ce{H2}$ there are $3$ translational + $2$ rotational degrees of freedom; $f = 5$

***What about efficiency?***

I have worked with Otto's engine model (real heat engines; internal combustion):

$$\eta = 1 - \left(\frac{V_2}{V_1} \right)^{\gamma -1}$$

Usually the compression ratio is of the order:

$$\frac{V_1}{V_2} = 8$$

Where $\gamma$ is the adiabatic exponent:

$$\gamma = \frac{f + 2}{f}$$

Thus, the efficiency of a gasoline engine:

$$\eta = 0.12$$

While the efficiency of an hydrogen engine:

$$\eta = 0.56$$

**My point is that the efficiency I get for gasoline is not what I expected (at least $0.20$). So I must be missing something on calculating the degrees of freedom for octane.**

Thus hydrogen is a more efficient fuel.

Comment: Once again, it is remarkable that this question (as many textbooks and lectures) selects the combustion reaction of octane of all the possible combustion reactions of gasoline to show the principle of combustion, although **gasoline actually does not contain much octane** (typically less than 1 %).

Comment: I'm also not sure that a purely theoretical definition of "efficiency" is remotely useful. In the real world we have to think of ideal like "how much energy can we extract per unit mass or unit volume" and we have to worry about the mass and volume of the tank required to store the fuel. Hydrogen is bad for both whatever the theory says about the combustion reaction.

Comment: Theoretically speaking hydrogen is more efficient than gasoline though. However, I am still thinking where I got wrong while calculating the degrees of freedom for octane; $f = 31$ doesn't make sense

Comment: I see inconsistencies between the equations for Cv or degrees of freedom, maybe because you consider vibrational degrees to contribute kT.

Comment: @NightWriter Thanks for your comment. Note that for getting $f$ I just had to divide $\frac{c_v}{R}$. Vibrational degrees of freedom should be frozen out here; I am sure $c_v$ has been calculated at temperatures below $1000K$

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, the vibrations hardly contribute, and I see how you got #df. But, shouldn't you have divided by R/2 rather than R? For each molecule, each quadratic d.f. possesses kT/2 of energy according to equipartition. That would make total d.f. for octane even greater, and the efficiency, by your equation, smaller, according to my calculation.

Comment: @NightWriter 2 cancels out with $n= 2$ Let me know if you don't see it.

Comment: I see that the reaction equation has a stoichiometric coefficient of 2 on front of octane, but am not sure I understand why that should be used in your CV expression for a *mole* of octane (or, is it a mole of reaction?).

Comment: I don't think that the degrees of freedom are the problem. You calculated them using an experimental value, so you get an effective number of active degrees of freedom, at that given temperature. Using $\gamma = 1.41$ for $\ce{H2}$ and  $\gamma = 1.05$ for octane, I got $\eta = 0.57$ and $0.10$, respectively. I guess that the low value for octane efficiency comes from the fact that you have a mixture of gases in the engine, so, realistically,  $\gamma$ will be closer to $1.40$ (value for air) and the efficiency will be larger than $0.10$.

Comment: @NightWriter note that we are dealing with 2 moles of octane in the reaction instead of 1. We are defenitely interested in what happens with 2 moles

Comment: @AntoniodeOliveira-Filho the calculations I did seem to have no mistakes but I simply do not understand why $f = 31$. I actually was expecting 3 translational degrees of freedom + 2 rotational, so $f = 5$ (like a diatomic molecule). Note that the temperature at which this process develops does not trigger vibrational degrees of freedom.

Comment: So my point is that I am clearly missing something in here...

Comment: Many vibrational modes in octane have low vibrational frequencies and they can be thermally excited therefore contributing to the calorific capacity.

Comment: @AntoniodeOliveira-Filho Can you provide a source enforcing such idea? I have always understood that under $1000k$ vibrational degrees of freedom are frozen out.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, your specific heat is provided as the molar heat capacity, $C_{v,m}$, where $C_{v,m}=\frac{C_v}{n}=\frac{\delta U}{\delta T}\cdot \frac{1}{n}=\frac{fR}{2}$ in this context. Right now, your units from $C_v=fR$ have $J/K/mol=J/K$.

Comment: @Blaise are you suggesting I should divide by 2 both sides, getting $f \approx 15$?

Comment: @JD_PM Just on the right side. I've never used this model, so I don't know why you expect butane to be above 0.20 efficiency, but this correction will produce your expected value above 0.20 efficiency. You can read this here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity#The_simple_case_of_the_monatomic_gas . There is no $n$ on the right-side, so your $f$ comes out between 15-16, and your units in the last step will match.

Comment: @JD_PM Here is a list of the harmonic vibrational frequencies for n-octave from NIST CCCBDB https://cccbdb.nist.gov/vibs3x.asp?method=90&basis=18 . A mode with $100 \,\text{cm}^{-1}$ has a vibrational temperature of $144$ K, which means that above this temperature, it contributes for the vibrational heat capacity. https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Map%3A_Physical_Chemistry_(McQuarrie_and_Simon)/18%3A_Partition_Functions_and_Ideal_Gases/18.4%3A_Most_Molecules_are_in_the_Ground_Vibrational_State, se Fig. 18.4.1.

Comment: @JD_PM Note also that each vibrational degree of freedom, in the high-temperature limit, contributes with $R$ to the heat capacity. There are two quadratic  terms in the vibrational energy $E_v = \frac{p^2}{2\mu} + \frac{1}{2}kx^2$. https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Map%3A_Physical_Chemistry_(McQuarrie_and_Simon)/18%3A_Partition_Functions_and_Ideal_Gases/The_Equipartition_Principle

Comment: You could have written the equation as:$$\ce{C8H18 + 25/2 O2 -> 9 H2O + 8 CO2}$$
This would not affect the value of the molar heat capacity, yet you use n=2 in arguing about its magnitude. Other quantities such as the Gibbs energy of reaction do depend on whether you multiply the equation by a constant factor, but the properties of the reaction species do not (that would be like trying to adjust the molar mass of a reactant by the stoichiometric coefficient).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like most of your confusion is coming from the fact that you are assuming that the vibrational degrees of freedom are completely frozen out at moderate temp. This is a common misconception. To see that this assumption is not true, we can look at the simple example of carbon dioxide. It is a linear molecule, so it has three degrees of translational freedom and two of rotation. If vibrational modes do not contribute at all, we expect that $\overline{C}_v=\frac52 R$ and $\overline{C}_p=\frac72 R$, so $\gamma=\dfrac{C_p}{C_v}=1.4$. If we include the 4 vibrational degrees of freedom, each of which contributes 1R to $\overline{C}_v$, we would have $\dfrac{C_p}{C_v}=1.15$. The experimental value at $20$ $^\circ C$ is about 1.3, indicating that the vibrational modes are already contributing to the heat capacity at this temperature. A plot of the heat capacity as a function of temp shows a gradual increase across a very wide range of temperature.

More rigorously, the contribution of a vibrational degree of freedom to the molar heat capacity is

$$R\cdot\left(\frac{\Theta}{T}\right)^2\cdot\frac{e^{\Theta/T}}{(e^{\Theta/T}-1)^2},$$

where the "vibrational temperature" $\Theta=\dfrac{hcv}{k_B}$. For the lowest energy vibrational normal modes of $\ce{CO2}$, $v=667 cm^{-1}$, so $\Theta = 961 K$. Although this is quite a bit higher than typical temperatures of interest, the above expression tells us that these vibrations contribute $\sim 0.45 R$ to $\overline{C}_v$ at 300 K. Since there are two modes at this frequency in $\ce{CO2}$, we expect that $\overline{C}_v$ and $\overline{C}_p$ are both increased by 0.9R at 300 K relative to the values excluding vibrations. This correction gives a value of $\dfrac{C_p}{C_v}$ very close to observed experimental value.

Going back to your case of octane, there are a number of normal modes with frequencies around 720 cm$^{-1}$, certainly low enough to contribute at 300 K. We have 18 + 8 = 26 total atoms, so we expect a maximum of 3*26=78 degrees of freedom. Since octane is not linear (in the strict sense of all atoms in a single line), there are 6 non-vibrational DOF. Thus, we expect that the number of degrees of freedom calculated using your method based on the experimental specific heat should be somewhere between these numbers.

Your calculation, however, needs to be corrected to account for the fact that vibrational degrees of freedom contribute 1R rather than R/2, so the equation becomes

$$\overline{C}_v = 3 R + (f-6)R.$$

From that, I get $f=33.8$, well within our expected range. You can repeat the rigorous calculation using the exact frequency of each normal mode of octane and see how close the result is to the experimental value.

UPDATE: To address the efficiency calculation, note that including the vibrational modes changes your equation for $\gamma$. Now we have that $\overline{C}_v=R(3+f-6)$ for (nonlinear) octane and $\overline{C}_v=R(\frac52)$ for hydrogen (ignoring its one vibrational mode). If we use the apparent degrees of freedom of octane of 33.8, $\gamma_{octane}=1.0325$ and $\gamma_{H2}=1.4$. [Note also that there is really no reason to calculate those apparent degrees of freedom except for curiosity, since we can just add R to the given $\overline{C}_v$ to get $\overline{C}_p$ and divide to get $\gamma_{octane}$.] From that I get an efficiency of 6.5% for the octane and 56% for the hydrogen.